# Как с помощью команды find искать файлы по размеру в определённом интервале?

Tags: linux

Нужно вывести количество файлов в папке и её под папках в интервале от одного ГБ и больше. Пользуюсь командой find:

```
find . -type f   -size +1G | wc -l;
```

Но она не учитывает файлы размером ровно один гигабайт (>1G). Как нужно её дополнить, чтобы был интервал >=1G ?

Спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно добавить еще одно условие используя ключ `-o`

```
find . -type f \( -size +1G -o -size 1G \) | wc -l;
```

Answer (score 3):

можно искать, указывая размер на один байт меньше — 1073741823:

```
$ find ... -size +1073741823c
```

---

вычисления можно поручить и самой оболочке:

```
$ find ... -size +$((1024*1024*1024-1))c
```