# Найти файлы больше определенного размера (ssh)

Tags: ssh, putty

Что добавить в команду, если мне нужны файлы больше 5мб(через putty)?

```
find /home/www/ -type f -iname "*.zip";
```

Я еле-еле нашел несколько гайдов, но все они бездумно скопированы :(, с очень смешной шуткой.

Для поиска файлов, размер которых превышает 1 Мб, предназначена команда

```
$ find . -aize -flOOOk -print*
```

Это нифига не работает, даже если заменить буквы `"о"` на нули, aize на size и т.д.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как с помощью команды find искать файлы по размеру в определённом интервале?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/643773/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d1%8b-find-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%83-%d0%b2-%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bc-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5)

Answer (score 2):

Вы не правы

Остались еще в интернете руководства, которые бездумно скопированы откуда то из другого места, например, [это](https://www.linux.com/topic/desktop/how-search-files-linux-command-line/)

Команда: `sudo find / -size +1000M`

А более опытный *EOF* подсказал еще лучшую команду в комментариях:

```
    find / -type f -size +10M -iname "*.zip"
```

Comment: Вот и это походу бездумно скопировано.
Потому что выдает ошибку find: invalid -size type `B'

EOF, Спасибо, ваш вариант работает.

Comment: @Amigo9876 - Да, согласен. Исправил ответ, убрал лишнюю `B` из надписи `+1000MB`

Comment: Ну, более опытный в гуглении:) Просто нашёл вот эту статью: https://pingvinus.ru/note/find-big-files

Comment: мама родная… автору ответа и вопроса срочно надо почитать `$ man man`, а затем `$ man find`.

Comment: Я прошу прощения, если вы скажете что мой ответ - плохой, я готов его удалить. Но. Ман по файнду занимает более тысячи строк - без поиска, без гиперссылок, и, самое главное, мне из всего этого мана нужно 3-4 ключа. Когда мне понадобятся коды возврата или другая экзотика, котрую нельзя прочитать иначе - я готов обратиться к ману, а до этого - мне проще погуглить.